# Query Returns 96 but ResultSet returns 0

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So I am trying to check and see if all seats on a plane have been booked yet.

I do this with the follow method:

```
public static boolean isAllBooked() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SEAT WHERE BOOKED IS NULL";
    boolean res = false;
    try(Connection conn = getConnection("", "");
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
           int i = rs.getInt(1);
           if(i == 0) {
               res = true;
           }
        } else {
            res = false;
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("[HELPER CLASS] SQL ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return res;
}
```

But for some reason, the query when used in SQLDeveloper returns 96 while the result returns 0. I have tried to wrap my head around this but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I had the same problem once when I forgot to commit my transaction in SQL Developer

Comment: It might be worth checking [`ResultSet.wasNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()) after calling `getInt` to see whether the result was actually 0 or null.

Comment: @andersschuller Nope. It's not null.

Comment: The conn.close() is redundant here, but you should close the ResultSet, or include it in the try-statement.

Comment: @EJP Alright. I am still confused as to why the resultset would return 0 as the int and not anything above 0, considering every single row is null in terms of values right now. It should return 96.

Answer (score 0):

You may have tried these already but thought still wont't hurt to ask.

1. Make sure you accessing same database from your app as you are using in database SQLDeveloper.
2. Try to step though your code in debugger. If you cannot debug for some reason put more log statements.
3. What is your getConnection() method doing. Check for possibilities of a unchecked exception or an exception other than SQLException thrown and swallowed somewhere. Because your method is only handling SQLException.

I hope it helps you solve your issue. :)

Comment: 1. I looked at that, and yes I connect to the same database.

2. I have tried that, but no errors or exceptions whatsoever.

3. No errors thrown or anything. Everything would be printed to the console.

Comment: What is the datatype of BOOKED?

Comment: check this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/oraext3.htm little old but may be of some help. Try using setNull method. Search for "Converting SQL NULL Data"

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see. The datatype is number.

Comment: Did you try to use setNull?

Comment: Why would I use setNull?

Comment: *How* could he use 'setNull()'? What's the purpose of that question?

Comment: I was reading at oracle link that I added in my previous comment. What I meant give it a try. Try to change String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SEAT WHERE BOOKED IS NULL"; to String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SEAT WHERE BOOKED = ?"; and then use st.setNull(1,Types.INTEGER);  I am not sure if it work. But may be worth a try.